# await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules javascript express error

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, async-await

This code is to verify firebase authentication. Firstly, it checks the req.headers.Then retrieve uid from the token. After the decodedToken.uid is received, the code will check with its own MySQL database to obtain the id of the user using `getID(uid)` function. If the uid is not in the database, it will create a new user using the function `makeNewUser()`. When executed, the code returns an error of "await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules". How can I fix this? Should I make a new file to handle that stuff and the return from this code should be stored in res.locals? Here is the code.

```
const admin = require('./config/firebaseAuth'); // import admin from firebase initializeApp
const getId = require('../utils/getUserID'); // module to get userId form MySQL database
const makeNewUser = require('../utils/makeNewUser'); // module to make a new user into MySQL database


class Middleware {
    async decodeToken(req,res,next) {
        // get authorization from the headers
        const { authorization } = req.headers; 

        // check if the authorization headers are well configured
        // this includes checking if headers.authorization exist
        // then if the format in headers.authorization matches with the configured
        if (!authorization) return res.status(403).json({
            status: 'fail', 
            type: 'server/missing-authorization',
            message: 'Missing req.headers.authorization on request to the server. This is need for authorization!'
        })

        else if (!authorization.startWith('Bearer')) return res.status(400).json({
            status: 'fail', 
            type: 'server/missing-bearer',
            message: 'Missing Bearer in req.headers.authorization on request to the server. This is needed to extract the token!'
        })

        else if (authorization.split(' ').length !== 2) return res.status(400).json({
            status: 'fail',
            type: 'server/bearer-unrecognized',
            message: 'Bearer in req.headers.authorization is not well configured. This is need to extract the token!'
        })
        // after passing the authorization header checks, now checks the token
        const token = authorization.split(' ')[1]; // req.headers = {"Bearer $.token"} 
        admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)
            .then((decodedToken) => {
                const {uid, name} = decodedToken; // get uid and name from the token
                try {
                    // !this produces an error: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
                    const result = await getId(uid); // getId to get the id of the user regarding the uid
                    // check if exist uid in the database
                    if (result.length < 1) {
                        // if not make a new user
                        const result = await makeNewUser(uid, name); // make new user from the given uid and name
                        const id = result.insertId; // get the id of the new user
                        req.user = {id: id, name: name}; // set id and name to req.user
                        return next();
                    }
                    const id = result[0].id; // getId to get the id of the user from the result query since uid exist
                    req.user = {id: id, name: name}; // set id and name to req.user 
                    return next();
                } catch (err) {
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        status: 'fail',
                        type: 'database/fail-to-query',
                        message: err.message
                    })
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                /*
                on err for firebase tokens, such as sent was FMC token instead of id token or token has expired and many others!
                err response: after executing console.log(err)
                {
                    errorInfo: {
                    code: 'auth/argument-error',
                    message: 'Decoding Firebase ID token failed. Make sure you passed the entire string JWT which represents an ID token. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.'
                    },
                    codePrefix: 'auth'
                }
                or
                {
                    errorInfo: {
                        code: 'auth/id-token-expired',
                        message: 'Firebase ID token has expired. Get a fresh ID token from your client app and try again (auth/id-token-expired). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.'
                    },
                    codePrefix: 'auth'
                }
                */
                if (err.errorInfo.code === 'auth/internal-error') var statusCode = 500;
                else var statusCode = 400; 
                return res.status(statusCode).json({status: "fail", type: err.errorInfo.code, message: err.errorInfo.message}); // return with status codes
            })
    }
}

module.exports = new Middleware();
```

Notes: getId and makeNewUser returns a promise!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Make the `(decodedToken) => {...}` function asynchronous: `async (decodedToken) => {...}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
const admin = require('./config/firebaseAuth'); // import admin from firebase initializeApp
    const getId = require('../utils/getUserID'); // module to get userId form MySQL database
    const makeNewUser = require('../utils/makeNewUser'); // module to make a new user into MySQL database
    
    
    class Middleware {
        async decodeToken(req,res,next) {
            // get authorization from the headers
            const { authorization } = req.headers; 
    
            // check if the authorization headers are well configured
            // this includes checking if headers.authorization exist
            // then if the format in headers.authorization matches with the configured
            if (!authorization) return res.status(403).json({
                status: 'fail', 
                type: 'server/missing-authorization',
                message: 'Missing req.headers.authorization on request to the server. This is need for authorization!'
            })
    
            else if (!authorization.startWith('Bearer')) return res.status(400).json({
                status: 'fail', 
                type: 'server/missing-bearer',
                message: 'Missing Bearer in req.headers.authorization on request to the server. This is needed to extract the token!'
            })
    
            else if (authorization.split(' ').length !== 2) return res.status(400).json({
                status: 'fail',
                type: 'server/bearer-unrecognized',
                message: 'Bearer in req.headers.authorization is not well configured. This is need to extract the token!'
            })
            // after passing the authorization header checks, now checks the token
            const token = authorization.split(' ')[1]; // req.headers = {"Bearer $.token"} 
            admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)
                .then( async (decodedToken) => {
                    const {uid, name} = decodedToken; // get uid and name from the token
                    try {
                        // !this produces an error: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
                        const result = await getId(uid); // getId to get the id of the user regarding the uid
                        // check if exist uid in the database
                        if (result.length < 1) {
                            // if not make a new user
                            const result = await makeNewUser(uid, name); // make new user from the given uid and name
                            const id = result.insertId; // get the id of the new user
                            req.user = {id: id, name: name}; // set id and name to req.user
                            return next();
                        }
                        const id = result[0].id; // getId to get the id of the user from the result query since uid exist
                        req.user = {id: id, name: name}; // set id and name to req.user 
                        return next();
                    } catch (err) {
                        return res.status(500).json({
                            status: 'fail',
                            type: 'database/fail-to-query',
                            message: err.message
                        })
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    /*
                    on err for firebase tokens, such as sent was FMC token instead of id token or token has expired and many others!
                    err response: after executing console.log(err)
                    {
                        errorInfo: {
                        code: 'auth/argument-error',
                        message: 'Decoding Firebase ID token failed. Make sure you passed the entire string JWT which represents an ID token. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.'
                        },
                        codePrefix: 'auth'
                    }
                    or
                    {
                        errorInfo: {
                            code: 'auth/id-token-expired',
                            message: 'Firebase ID token has expired. Get a fresh ID token from your client app and try again (auth/id-token-expired). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.'
                        },
                        codePrefix: 'auth'
                    }
                    */
                    if (err.errorInfo.code === 'auth/internal-error') var statusCode = 500;
                    else var statusCode = 400; 
                    return res.status(statusCode).json({status: "fail", type: err.errorInfo.code, message: err.errorInfo.message}); // return with status codes
                })
        }
    }
    
    module.exports = new Middleware();
```